# How to calculate the difference between columns by column in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with the following values:

| source | ACCESS CREATED | TERMS SIGNED | BUREAU |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Facebook | 12 | 8 | 6 |
| Google | 160 | 136 | 121 |
| Email | 29 | 26 | 25 |

This is a small example of this dataframe, actually there are more rows and columns in them, but maybe for example it should help.

The outuput (in percentage):

| source | ACCESS CREATED | TERMS SIGNED | BUREAU |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Facebook | 0 | 33 | 17 |
| Google | 0 | 15 | 9 |
| Email | 0 | 10 | 3 |

How to create a new dataframe with the difference (in percentage) from one column to another, for example: COLUMN A: 12, COLUMN B: 8, so the difference in this step is 33%, and from COLUMN C: 6, and the difference from B to C is 17%. The calculus: (8/12) = 67% (100%-67%)=33%, next column: (6/12)=50% (67% - 50%)=17%,  next column: (4/12)=33% (50%-33%)=17% and so on...

Comment: Hiya, it's generally a good idea to show what you have so far, and explain what's going wrong. In particular it's good to show what you've tried with a code example. This might allow people to spot mistakes you haven't thought of.

For example, are you having trouble with the percentage calculation, combining the dataframes etc?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df['TERMS SIGNED'] = ((1 - df['TERMS SIGNED']/df['ACCESS CREATED']) * 100).round()
df['BUREAU'] = 100 - df['TERMS SIGNED'] - (1 - df['BUREAU']/df['ACCESS CREATED']) * 100
df['ACCESS CREATED'] = 0
```